# How can I remove or modify this H2 tag from my WordPress theme?

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors

How can I remove or modify this `h2` tag from my WordPress theme?

[image: Recent Orders heading]

Comment: With the information you provided we are not able to help you. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a css selector which is as specific as possible and apply `display: none;`  to that

It seems you are using Chrome, so you can open the browser tools as you did and right-click on that element. In the appearing context menu, there's an entry "copy" and a submenu entry "copy selector". This should give you a useable selector for that purpose which you can paste into your stylesheet or into the Wordpress customizer / "additional CSS".

The result would look something like this:

```
#dashbord-tab-due-373 > .jobsearch-employer-dashboard > .jobsearch-employer-box-section > h2:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

(actually this rule should work in the particular example you posted, but my description above is more general)